# How to extract telemetry code from different methods? Decorator pattern? AOP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, aspectj, azure-application-insights

We are using Application Insights to monitor different service calls in our applications. Data for Application Insights is provided by many different methods and classes but always in an identical way/by identical code fragments:

```java
public class MyClassA {

  public void myMethodA() {
    final Instant startTime = Instant.now();

    try {
      callSomeServiceA();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      sendExceptionDataToAppInsights(e);
      throw e;
    } finally {
      sendDataToAppInsights(MyClass.getName(), myMethodA.getName(), startTime, Instant.now());  
    }
  }

}

public class MyClassB {

  public String myMethodB() {
    final Instant startTime = Instant.now();

    try {
      return callSomeServiceB();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      sendExceptionDataToAppInsights(e);
      throw e;
    } finally {
      sendDataToAppInsights(MyClass.getName(), myMethodA.getName(), startTime, Instant.now());  
    }
  }

}
```

How am I able to extract those wrapping try catch fragments to one point of responsibility? I took a look at the dacorator pattern but I guess it doesn't fit because of the different method signatures. Or does it?
Or is there a way to achieve it with AOP?

Comment: what is the relation between those classes and those methods?

Comment: There isn't really any relation between those. They are even spread across different micro-services.

Comment: Maybe you should an actual example, since as the one you provided won't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is the paradigm to modularize cross-cutting concerns such as logging, monitoring and error handling (your particular case).

The most popular framework to achieve this in Java is [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), which can be used from any Spring project via the `spring-boot-starter-aop` dependency.

#### Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${aop-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```
implementation `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${aop-version}`
```

The simplest way to achieve what you're asking is to make an aspect (using `@Aspect`) that uses `@Around`. There are plenty of examples of this online. Your execution ([`ProceedingJoinPoint`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html)`:: proceed`) will need to happen inside a try-catch block very similar to what you have in your question:

```java
@Around("execution(<aspectj-selector-here>)")
public void anyMethodName(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    // try-catch blocks here...
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, thank you. But is there a way to insert parameter into aspect implementation? I need to pass parameters to `sendDataToAppInsights`

Comment: the methods on [`ProceedingJoinPoint`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html) (the `pjp` i mention above, an argument to your aspect method) have everything you need :)

Comment: @PaulBenn If you don't like the edit fell free to rollback